# Error al pasar interfaz por parámetro , putExtra

Tags: java, android-studio

tengo un problema con un modal, tengo una clase A q abre un Modal B y necesito que en el Modal B vayas a una clase C que se seleccione un objeto X y vuelva al Modal B con ese objeto seleccionado. El problema que no me deja pasar la interfaz por parámetro ni de ninguna forma

Clase Modal B

```
 clase: AceptarRechazarCobroModal extends BottomSheetDialogFragment

     btn_select_method.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                iAcciones.mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas(solicitudModel, AceptarRechazarCobroModal.this);
                // cobrar=new ElegirCuentasACobrar(solicitudModel,AceptarRechazarCobroModal.this);
            }
        });
```

Clase A

Implementa la interfaz y mada interfaz por paramtro a clase A :

```
@Override
public void mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas(final SolicitantesModel solicitud, IaceptarCobroDevolver iAceptarCobroDevolver ) {

        goToSeleccionarMetodoCobro(solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum.CONFIRMAR_COBRO, iAceptarCobroDevolver);
    }


> Clase MasterController

  protected void goToSeleccionarMetodoCobro(SolicitantesModel solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoTransaccion, IaceptarCobroDevolver iaceptarCobroDevolver) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MasterController.this,
                ElegirCuentasACobrar.class);

        intent.putExtra("SolicitudActividadInterface", iaceptarCobroDevolver);
        intent.putExtra("SolicitudActividad", solicitud);
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.putExtraTipoTransaccion), tipoTransaccion);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

El error es que no me deja mandar la interface por el putExtra , se me cae la app

Clase C recibe los parámetros del intent.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 solicitud = (SolicitantesModel) intent.getSerializableExtra("SolicitudActividad");
 iaceptarCobroDevolver = (IaceptarCobroDevolver) intent.getSerializableExtra("SolicitudActividadInterface");
}
```

Comment: No "*creas*", usa el debugger! Para qué está el logcat y la consola si no es para ver qué ha ocurrido cuando crashea? Te tiene que aparecer una traza del error, sin eso es imposible ayudarte. Por cierto, imagino que habrás implementado la interfaz `Serializable` para poder meterlo así, no?

Comment: este es el error que salta en el locat : Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView

Comment: Si puse Serializable

Comment: Estás intentando meter un MaterialTextView?!?! Cómo esperas pasar un elemento de la vista a otra vista?? Una vez que esa vista desaparezca, ese MTV no existirá. Lo que debes pasar es su valor, no el elemento en sí...

Comment: no hay forma de pasar solo la  interfaz? , no quiero pasar ningún materialTextView

Comment: No lo que estás intentando hacer. Quieres pasar una ... interfaz? Supongo que una clase que implementa una interfaz tuya, no?? Necesitaría ver la definición de la interfaz, aparte de eso, no es "correcto" meter cosas directamente al intent, lo mejor es usar un bundle donde metes las cosas que quieres pasar, y en la segunda actividad recoges el bundle con `getExtras()` y del bundle ya puedes sacar todo

Comment: y esta la que quiero pasar

Comment: public interface IaceptarCobroDevolver extends Serializable {
    void origenSeleccionadoAceptarCobroDevolver(Cuenta cuenta, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVuelta, SolicitantesModel solicitud );
}

Answer (score 0):

```
  Esta es la clase del MODAL 



public class AceptarRechazarCobroModal extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements IaceptarCobroDevolver {

    SolicitantesModel solicitudModel;
    IAccionesHomeController iAcciones;
Cuenta cuentaDevuelta;
    private IaceptarCobroDevolver iaceptarCobroDevolver;
    Cuenta lstCuentas;
    ElegirCuentasACobrar cobrar;
  //  IAceptarCobro iAceptarCobro;
    TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVuelta;

    public AceptarRechazarCobroModal(Cuenta lstCuentas, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVuelta,IAccionesHomeController iAcciones) {
        this.lstCuentas = lstCuentas;
        this.tipoVuelta = tipoVuelta;
        this.iAcciones=iAcciones;
        //iAcciones.mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas();
       // iAcciones.mostrarListaTarjetasCuentasAcept();
    }


    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = (BottomSheetDialog) super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        View view = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.solicitud_de_cobro, null);
        bottomSheet.setContentView(view);

        TextView strLblName = view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_solicitante);
        TextView strLblMonto = view.findViewById(R.id.monto_solicitud);
        TextView strLblRef = view.findViewById(R.id.ref_solicitud);
        TextView btnRechazar = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_rechazar);
        ImageView btn_close = view.findViewById(R.id.close_bottomsheet);
        ImageView btn_select_method = view.findViewById(R.id.imgSelectMethod);

        ImageView fotoPerfil = view.findViewById(R.id.foto_solicitante);
        final SeekBar seekBarPagar = view.findViewById(R.id.SeekBarContinuar);
        iniComponentes();
        strLblName.setText(solicitudModel.getFirstName());
        strLblMonto.setText(formateadorDeSaldos(solicitudModel.getMonto()));
        strLblRef.setText(solicitudModel.getDetalle());
        if(!solicitudModel.getImage().equals("") || solicitudModel.getImage() != null){
            if (!solicitudModel.getImage().equals("s/d")) {
                fotoPerfil.setImageBitmap(ImageUtil.convert(solicitudModel.getImage()));
            }
        }



        btn_select_method.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                iAcciones.mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas(solicitudModel, AceptarRechazarCobroModal.this);
                // cobrar=new ElegirCuentasACobrar(solicitudModel,AceptarRechazarCobroModal.this);
            }
        });

        seekBarPagar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    seekBarPagar.setProgress(seekBarPagar.getProgress());
                    return false;
                }
                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    seekBarPagar.setProgress(0);
                    seekBarPagar.setProgress(0);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        seekBarPagar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(progress == 100){
                    iAcciones.aceptarCobro(solicitudModel);
                    dismiss();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                if (seekBar.getProgress() < 100){
                    seekBar.setProgress(0);
                }
            }
        });

        btnRechazar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                iAcciones.rechazarCobro(solicitudModel);
                dismiss();

            }
        });

        btn_close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                dismiss();
            }
        });

        bottomSheet.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
                BottomSheetDialog d = (BottomSheetDialog) dialog;

                FrameLayout bottomSheet = (FrameLayout) d.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.design_bottom_sheet);
                BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet).setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            }
        });


        return bottomSheet;
    }
    private void iniComponentes() {

        iaceptarCobroDevolver = this;
    }
    public AceptarRechazarCobroModal(SolicitantesModel solicitud, IAccionesHomeController iAcciones) {
        solicitudModel = solicitud;
        this.iAcciones = iAcciones;
    }


    @Override
    public void origenSeleccionadoAceptarCobroDevolver(Cuenta cuenta, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVueltas, SolicitantesModel solicitud) {
        cuentaDevuelta=cuenta;
        solicitudModel=solicitud;
        tipoVuelta=tipoVueltas;

    }
}
```

lA MINTERFAZ

```
public interface IaceptarCobroDevolver extends Serializable {
    void origenSeleccionadoAceptarCobroDevolver(Cuenta cuenta, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoVuelta, SolicitantesModel solicitud );
}
```

PASO LOS PARAMETROS

```
 @Override
    public void mostrarListaTarjetasCuentas(final SolicitantesModel solicitud, IaceptarCobroDevolver iAceptarCobroDevolver ) {

        goToSeleccionarMetodoCobro(solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum.CONFIRMAR_COBRO, iAceptarCobroDevolver);
    }
```

EN LOS PASO A LA MASTER

```
protected void goToSeleccionarMetodoCobro(SolicitantesModel solicitud, TipoTransaccionEnum tipoTransaccion, IaceptarCobroDevolver iaceptarCobroDevolver) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MasterController.this,
                ElegirCuentasACobrar.class);

        intent.putExtra("SolicitudActividadInterface", iaceptarCobroDevolver);
        intent.putExtra("SolicitudActividad", solicitud);
        intent.putExtra(getString(R.string.putExtraTipoTransaccion), tipoTransaccion);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Te falta agregar la explicacion a la solucion que das.

Comment: jaja es parte de la  explicación así capas q se entiende mas